# Is there any way to override the "network/ipc" container in the kubernetes pod declaration?

Tags: docker, containers, kubernetes

I want to be able to override the `gcr.io/google_containers/pause` container only in a single pod. I'm having trouble finding in the documentation if it's possible at all.

I'm trying to set up a VPN client container/pod and use it's networking namespace to connect to an remote DC, but only for a single pod group.

The closest I have found is the `--pod-infra-container-image` flag on kubelet, which would modify it for all pods.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As the other answer suggests, this is not configurable per pod.

If you really want to achieve this through the custom infra container image and you have multiple nodes (and are willing to dedicate one node for this purpose), you can configure one node to use your custom infra container image. You should then label and [taint](https://github.com/kubernetes/community/blob/master/contributors/design-proposals/taint-toleration-dedicated.md) the node such that

1. The group of pods can only be scheduled onto the special node based on the node selector in the pod spec.
2. Other pods cannot be scheduled onto the special node because they cannot tolerate the taint.

Answer (score 0):

No, that container is designed to be uniform for all pods, and is not intended to be under the control of the API user.